# nodes lost after calling text() on self-closed element

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#test').text('a')
```

```html
<p>Hello <span id='test' /> World</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

The text "World" is lost after doing so.

If I don't self-close the span tag, "World" preserves.

Are there any documentations on this behavior?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for the editing, but after your edition, if I click the Run code button, the word "World" doesn't lose here, which may confuse readers.

Comment: Really? It disappears for me, on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and even Internet Explorer. Are you sure? What browser are you on?

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh, it's my adblocker that blocks something.

Answer (score 1):

A span is not a self-closing tag. Only void elements (like `<input>`, `<br>`) can have this sort of logic (where an element is opened and closed with a single `<...>`), but even then, the `/>` doesn't do anything. On non-void elements, even if you put `/>` into the HTML, the browser will interpret it as a plain opening tag, ignoring the `/`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#test').outerHTML);
```

```html
<p>Hello <span id='test'/> World</p>
```

You can only use it as a self-closing tag in XML or XHTML, or when you create the element via jQuery, eg:

```js
const $elements = $(`<p>Hello <span id='test'/> World</p>`);
console.log($elements[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, it makes sense.  `$('#test').text()` outptus "World".. Browser treats the following text as the content of the span.